# Join certain elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list that looks like this:

`lst = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l']]`

Can I join the first two elements in each list within `lst`, such that the output would look like this:

`new_list = [['ab','c','d'],['ef','g','h'],['ij','k','l']]`

If this was a flat list, I would write `lst[0:2] = [' '.join(lst[0:2])]`. I try to nest this code with a list comprehension:

`new_list = [[''.join(x[0:2]) for x[0:2] in group] for group in lst]`

But I do not get the desired output. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code here and how I accomplish the output above?

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> [["".join(l[:2])]+l[2:] for l in lst]
[['ab', 'c', 'd'], ['ef', 'g', 'h'], ['ij', 'k', 'l']]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a slight variation on @not_speshal's answer, you could use list comprehension with a splat operator:

```
lst = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l']]
res = [[a + b, *rest] for a, b, *rest in lst]
```

Comment: This answer feels more Pythonic to me. In this case, it's better than using indexes with constants, and looks cleaner (that is, less cluttered).